# Drawing TikZ box equal to the textwidth

Tags: tikz-pgf

Sorry if this has been asked before – I vaguely remember seeing something related to this, but can't find it anymore.

So I took a TeXample from here: [Boxes with text and math](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/boxes-with-text-and-math/). I edited it a tiny bit to make it shorter. Now, the problem is that although I specified the width of the box to be equal to the `\textwidth`, it seems to be a bit larger than the area from the left to the right margin, and it also shifted to the right (as is made clear from the `showframe` package. What it wrong here?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,decorations}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=red, fill=blue!20, very thick,
    rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=20pt]
\tikzstyle{fancytitle} =[fill=red, text=white]

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        Some text and math blah blah blah
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u\cos\psi -v\sin\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\sin\psi + v\cos\psi
        \end{align}
    \end{minipage}
};
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {A fancy title};
\node[fancytitle, rounded corners] at (box.east) {$\clubsuit$};
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: For those boxes you may also have a look at the `tcolorbox` package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `tcolorbox` is, by default, as wide as `\textwidth`, so you don't have to worry about its size and placement.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{%
    enhanced,
    title = #2, 
    attach boxed title to top left={%
        xshift=5mm, 
        yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2, 
        yshifttext=-1mm},
    boxed title style={colback=red, sharp corners},
    colframe = red,
    colback = blue!20,  
    overlay = {\node[text=white, fill=red] at (frame.east) 
        {$\clubsuit$};},
    #1}


\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}{A fancy title}%
        Some text and math blah blah blah
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u\cos\psi -v\sin\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\sin\psi + v\cos\psi
        \end{align}
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You have set the `inner sep = 10pt`, so you should subtract double that value from the width of the `minipage`, besides `\noindent` is also required.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,decorations}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=red, fill=blue!20, very thick,
    rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=20pt]
\tikzstyle{fancytitle} =[fill=red, text=white]

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
    \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-20pt}
        Some text and math blah blah blah
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u\cos\psi -v\sin\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\sin\psi + v\cos\psi
        \end{align}
    \end{minipage}
};
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {A fancy title};
\node[fancytitle, rounded corners] at (box.east) {$\clubsuit$};
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

[image]